# Angular 4 fire function after server data loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, fetch

How to fire function that requires back end data? My target is to fire `getPersons()` which depends on `getCities()` and `getCars()` with Angular 4.

```
export class Person {
  constructor(
    public cities: any[],
    public cars: any[]
  ) { }
}
```

In component I call:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCars();
    this.getCities();
    this.getPersons();
  }
```

***EDIT*** Service:

```
  public getCars(): Observable<CarsList> {
    return this.http.get(this.carsUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(
        this.errorHandlerService.showError(getCarsError)));
  }
```

Component:

```
 public getPersons(): void {
    this.personsService.getPersons()
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            this.persons = data;
            this.persons .forEach((person, index) => {
              person.carName = this.cars.find((car) => car.id === person.carId).name;
              console.log('error here because this.cars is still undefined')
            }
        )
 }
```

Problem is that `getPersons()` is fired before `getCities()` and `getCars()` are loaded and data depends on it. So `this.cities` or `this.cars` objects are null and app crash. How to fire `getPersons()` when `getCities()` and `getCars()` are loaded?
Already tried `AfterViewInit` with `setTimeout` workarounds which are not working.

Comment: How are they related? Are they asyncronous?

Comment: Please show the code of `getCars()`, `getCities()` and `getPersons()`.

Comment: updated added service and component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this way:
Service:

```
 public async getCars(): Promise<DetailedObjectsList> {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get(this.carsUrl).toPromise();
      return response.json();
    } catch (e) {
      this.errorHandlerService.showError(carsError);
    }
  }
```

Component:

```
  public async getCars() {
    await this.carsService.getCars()
      .then((data) => {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(data)) {
          this.cars = data.detailedObjects;
        }
      });
  }
```

and most important:

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getCars()
      .then(() => {
        this.getCities()
          .then(() => {
            this.getPersons();
        });
      });
  }
```

I hope that helps for you too.